# Serve resources from a consistent URL GT Metrix

Tags: themes, optimization

I am optimizing WordPress website speed and i have fixed all other issues mentioned by GT metrix (Website to test website speed) but could not fix Serve resources from a consistent URL.
I know there are multiple links that are calling a same resource and i have also figured out that this issue is in my theme because i have test by site by disabling plugins and child theme.
My parent theme is DIVI theme and i have tried a lot to find out these links in all files and in theme options but was not successful.
How i can fix this issue and find out these links ?

Comment: Please elaborate what is actual challenge here, most of people won't be familiar with reference to something some service out there suggest.

Comment: @Rarst i edit this question now to add more detail.

Comment: Have you confirmed the issues are coming from the child theme, or are any coming from the parent theme? In either case it's usually best to contact the theme author. If the issues are confirmed to be coming from the child theme, you can save a backup of the child theme, then delete it from your site. Then add the child theme folder with only the `style.css` file in it. If there are any issues, they are in `style.css`. Then add each file back into the child theme, one by one, until you discover which files contain the issues.

Comment: I am sure these these links are coming from parent theme because i have tried to activate parent theme.